# Changing default colors in tkz-base

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to change the black to white when using `tkz` packages, the ones I use the most are `tkz-fct` and `tkz-euclide`.

Is there a way of changing the colors of the text, background, fill etc. at will?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{mismath}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            
        \tkzInit[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5]
        \tkzDrawX[noticks, label=\(\Re\left(z\right)\),below right,thick]
        \tkzDrawY[noticks, label=\(\Im\left(z\right)\),thick]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O}\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[black,opacity=.2,inner sep=2mm](current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add your full attempt to the question, i.e., a small complete document with a small `fct` or `euclide` drawing in it and the (failed) redefinition of the color?

Comment: But as a first guess: the color macro has an `@` symbol in it so you need to surround the redefinition with `\makeatletter` (before) and `\makeatother` (after), so `\makeatletter\def\tkz@textcolor{white}\makeatother`.

Comment: @Marijn I've added the example with your solution which worked! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, good the the issue is solved. However, now there is no question anymore, which is not a good fit for the site. Because the topic itself is interesting for possible future readers, I propose that you split the post in two: a question post that states the problem (change the colors in `tkz-*` packages) with the document code, and an answer post that presents the solution (both the fragment from the `.cfg` file and the `\makeatletter` part).

Answer (score 2):

I've looked over the documentation and found, in `tkz-base.cfg`, the lines:

```
%<------   colors  ---------------------------------------–>
\def\tkz@backgroundcolor{white}
\def\tkz@textcolor{black}
%<---------------------------------------------------------
\def\tkz@fillcolor{\tkz@backgroundcolor}
\def\tkz@mainlinecolor{\tkz@textcolor}
\def\tkz@otherlinecolor{\tkz@mainlinecolor!50}
```

We can change these colors by overwriting the definitions in the document. Because the color names contain the `@` symbol we need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, as follows:

**Solution** *based on Marijn comment*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{mismath}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}

\makeatletter
   \def\tkz@textcolor{white}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5]
        \tkzDrawX[noticks, label=\(\Re\left(z\right)\),below right,thick]
        \tkzDrawY[noticks, label=\(\Im\left(z\right)\),thick]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O}\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[black,opacity=.2,inner sep=2mm](current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the question and answer a bit to separate the problem and the solution more clearly.